# Finding ASP.NET MVC User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm creating a custom ActionResult class and I need it to be able to operate on a `UserControl`. All of the examples I've found so far pass in the full path like so:

```
return MyResult("~/Areas/AreaName/Views/ControllerName/UserControlName.ascx", myModel);
```

That's pretty long so I'd like it to operate the same way as calling `View()`, i.e. I just pass in the name and MVC determines the correct route:

```
return MyResult("UserControlName", myModel);
```

Is there a way I can find out the correct route to the control without specifying it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not inherit from `ViewResult` and override the methods you need?